# C# change color in chart

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, charts

I have a chart in C# where I bind values to it. I have two different arrays with values and concat them to one chart. Now I wanted to display one part of the chart (with the values from the first array) in a different color. How to do this? drawing two charts causes errors so I wanted to do it this way. Here is a part of the code:

```
String[] x_axis = _temp_date1.Concat(_date).ToArray();
Double[] y_axis = _temp_data.Concat(_value).ToArray();

chart1.Series["Chart"].Points.DataBindXY(x_axis, y_axis);
chart1.Series["Chart"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;

chart1.Series["Chart"].Points[0].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
chart1.Series["Chart"].Points[1].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

The part with the Color doesn't work.

So lets say I have two arrays for the x values (date1 and date2) and two arrays for the y values (data1 and data2), Now I merge the date1 and date2 arrays and I merge the data1 and data2 arrays. I bind them to my graph. Now I would like to display the part of the graph in a different color where my values from the date1/data1 arrays come from. The array length can change because the data is read from a csv file.

Comment: OK. Now let's see: Before getting to colors: You seem to have problems combining two set of data? To do so properly you have two options: You can have two ChartAreas in the same Chart or you can Have two Series of data Points. Which to you want? Shall the areas be separate or overlaid? [Here is a Chart example](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC523407.png) with two ChartAreas and several Series in each..

Comment: I tried to make two separate charts but that didn't work. The values in both array were correct but the graph was broken instead of going through - both graphs overlapped and that shouldn't happen because the values in the arrays are continueing like it would be one data that was split up in two parts.

Comment: That sounds like you want to add a 2nd ChartArea to the Chart : `chart1.ChartAreas.Add["area2"]`

Comment: How does that work? Can you give a code example?

Comment: Just did that..It looks long but it is really very straightforward. Please note a few corrections with the coloring..

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that shows both: Two separate `ChartAreas` in the same `Chart` and two `Series` in the same `ChartArea`. Pick which you want:

```
// cleanup before we start 
chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
chart1.Series.Clear();
// two areas one on top the other below
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area1");
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area2");
// three series
chart1.Series.Add("series1");
chart1.Series.Add("series2");
chart1.Series.Add("series3");
// we assign  two series to the bottom area
chart1.Series["series1"].ChartArea = "area1";
chart1.Series["series2"].ChartArea = "area2";
chart1.Series["series3"].ChartArea = "area2";
// all series are of type spline
chart1.Series["series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
chart1.Series["series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
chart1.Series["series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
// each has a spearate color
chart1.Series["series1"].Color = Color.Red;
chart1.Series["series2"].Color = Color.Blue;
chart1.Series["series3"].Color = Color.Green;
// now we add a few points
chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddXY(1, 100);
chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddXY(2, 400);
chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddXY(3, 200);
chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddXY(4, 300);

chart1.Series["series2"].Points.AddXY(1, 120);
chart1.Series["series2"].Points.AddXY(2, 420);
chart1.Series["series2"].Points.AddXY(3, 290);
chart1.Series["series2"].Points.AddXY(4, 390);

chart1.Series["series3"].Points.AddXY(1, 220);
chart1.Series["series3"].Points.AddXY(2, 320);
chart1.Series["series3"].Points.AddXY(3, 690);
chart1.Series["series3"].Points.AddXY(4, 190);

// we can even paint a part of the spline curve in a different color
// to be precise: the part up to the point:
chart1.Series["series3"].Points[1].Color = Color.HotPink;
chart1.Series["series3"].Points[2].Color = Color.Orange;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Now if you simply want to change the color of the points after a certain number of points you could do it like this:

```
int start = x_axis.Length; 
for (int i = start ; i < chart1.Series[0].Points.Count; i++)
    chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Color = Color.Green;
```

Note that you need to set the color of **each** point that shall have a different color from the default chart color!

Comment: Ok now I have two seperate Areas with a graph in each. Can I put them together so that they don't appear one upon the other but side by side? that would be exactly what I need

Comment: No. If that's what you want, don't add a 2nd Area, simply add a 2nd 'Series', like in the bottom area!

Comment: The graphs overlap then. The values of the y-axis are just taken from the first array and both graphs are overlapping. I would rather place the areas side by side. Is that possible? - The first array has dates on the x-axis till April the 20th and the second array starts wit April 21th. He just takes the dates from Array1 and places the second graph on it

Comment: _I would rather place the areas side by side. Is that possible?_ Do you mean two areas, each with its own Axis etc, or do you want to have one curve that simply changes colors?

Comment: The best would be one curve that starts in the x-axis of array1 and goes through the x-axis of array2 and changes the color. So like you would have two graphs and put them simply together. The start of the second to the end of the first one and same with the x-axis.

Comment: Well in that case your original code is almost what you need anway: Simply change the color for each point in a the second array, just like you tried in the code or like you see in my code..

Comment: Yes - the first code was the closest one but how I change that? He doesn't accept the values Point[0] or Point[1]. Best way would be that after a certain array length the color get changed but with if-else statements and while loops I couldn't do that. He just displayed only one part of the graph or just one color

Comment: I have added an example. Your code has a typo: It is `Points` not `Point`

Comment: Did I place it wrong? doesn't work - I get the default color and when I bind the values in the "for loop" it will display nothing

Comment: Ok I will start another topic again because this is getting too long

Comment: I just saw it. Of course you can't paint a point before it is created ;-)

Comment: @TaW suppose if this graph dont have MajorGrid.I need to draw a line from x value to y value to show its connection. How do i do it?

Comment: You could draw onto the control or add a lineannotation. But both methods are problematic for various reasons. Instead I would add another Series for the purpose. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002464/how-to-draw-a-line-only-between-specific-points-in-the-same-chart-series/32049857#32049857) for an example of a series that displays connection lines between aribtrary datapoints

Answer (score 2):

In your `charts` control properties :

`Series` --> `Member[n]` --> `Color` --> `Red` , and so on

**OR**

```
chart1.Series["Chart"].Color = Color.Red
```

**Edit** (According to the discussion in the comments, you can try something like):

Say we have an array of `doubles`, and we want to plot it each portion in a different color :

```
Double[] data; // my data
int i=0;

chart1.Series["Chart"].Points[0].Clear(); // initialize the chart
chart1.Series["Chart"].Color = Color.Red; // initial color

for(i=0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
  if(i >= data.Length/2)
     chart1.Series["Chart"].Color = Color.Green; // use other color after certain data #

  chart1.Series["Chart"].Points.AddXY(i, data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Both doesn't work. The second one does not find the Series[0] and when I change it to Point I get a "OutOfRangeException". How can I change it depending an array length?

Comment: @uzi42tmp: you are not describing much by the work `don't work`! can I see how are you defining your chart?

Comment: I simply can't find the property. But the problem is that I don't want to change it manually because the x- and y-axis can change and I would like to color a part of it depending on the array length. The values are from two arrays merged together and they show a coherent graph

Comment: @uzi42tmp: Do you mean you have a single graph? and that you want to color parts of it with different colors ?

Comment: exactly! one part shall be colored depending on the size of an array so when the arraylength changes the area of the graph which is colored different should change too

Comment: I get always one unique color for the graph. Originaly I have two different arrays for the x-axis and two different for the y-axis. Then I concatenate them (both x-axis and both y-axis) and put them into the x- and y- values. I want to display the part of the graph where the values from the first array are displayed in a different color. That example above doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Edited my original post because I think my description was not clear enough. Sorry for that!

Comment: Is it Winforms??? Please __always__ tag your questions with WPF, ASP, WinFomrs...!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
            txtTableSQL.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            txtTableSQL.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(15, 15, 15);

            txtComandoSQL.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            txtComandoSQL.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(15, 15, 15);

            txtReport.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            txtReport.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(15, 15, 15);

            chartSeries.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            chartSeries.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(15, 15, 15);

            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            chartSeries.Series[0].Color = Color.Gray;
            chartSeries.Series[0].LabelForeColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.Series[0].BorderColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.Series[0].MarkerColor = Color.Black;


            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].Axes[0].LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].Axes[2].LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].Axes[3].LineColor = Color.Black;

            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            chartSeries.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleForeColor = Color.Black;

            chartSeries.Legends[0].BackColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?