# How to draw a Line only between specific points in the same Chart series

Tags: c#, plot, charts

I have the following issue:

- A distribution of points plotted on a dot chart;
- Some of those points need to be connected to each other in a way that
  a single point could be connected to several different points;
- Those points need to be connected with a line;
- Not all points could be connected.

Comment: The answers for this will vary greatly depending on whether you're using Mono, WPF/Windows Universal, or Forms.

Comment: Sorry, I hav totally misread your question. I hope the new answer does what you want..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Series can **either** be of type `Point` **or** `Line`, so we will need to either use **two** Series or resort to some tricks.

I suggest using two Series, as it is rather simple to code and maintain..

[image]

This screenshot shows 100 random points and 25 random connections between them.

A `Line` chart can only draw **one** line, connecting **all** its points, one after the other. So the trick is to add **two** points per conncection to the Line Series, alternating their Colors between invisible and some visible Color..:

First we set up the `Chart` with its two `Series` and a nice `Legend`:

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
// the series with all the points
Series SP = chart1.Series.Add("SPoint");
SP.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
SP.LegendText = "Data points";
// and the series with a few (visible) lines:
Series SL = chart1.Series.Add("SLine");
SL.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
SL.Color = Color.DarkOrange;
SL.LegendText = "Connections";
```

Now we create some random data; you will have to adapt to your data source..:

```
Random R = new Random(2015);  // I prefer repeatable randoms

List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();  // charts actually uses double by default
List<Point> lines = new List<Point>();

int pointCount = 100;
int lineCount = 25;

for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
    points.Add(new PointF(1 + R.Next(100), 1 + R.Next(50)));

for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
    lines.Add(new Point(R.Next(pointCount), R.Next(pointCount)));
```

Now we add the points, straightforward:

```
foreach (PointF pt in points) SP.Points.AddXY(pt.X, pt.Y);
```

..and the lines. Here I (ab)use a `Point` structure to simply store the two integer **indices** into the `points` data..:

```
foreach (Point ln in lines)
{
    int p0 = SL.Points.AddXY(points[ln.X].X, points[ln.X].Y);
    int p1 = SL.Points.AddXY(points[ln.Y].X, points[ln.Y].Y);
    SL.Points[p0].Color = Color.Transparent;
    SL.Points[p1].Color = Color.OrangeRed;
}
```

}

Done.

You could instead add `LineAnnotations` to one Series of Points, but that's not so simple, I'm afraid..

To **remove** a connection you would remove **both** points that make it up:

To remove connection `rc` use:

```
chart1.Series[1].Points.RemoveAt(rc * 2);  // remove 1st one
chart1.Series[1].Points.RemoveAt(rc * 2);  // remove 2nd one, now at the same spot
```